# Move my site content up Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am struggling to move my whole site up the page more. As you can see by the logo there is a big gap. How do I go about moving this up? 
[Website here. ][1]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit for wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: is this a spam? really?

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding in your css, comment it out

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* padding-top: 80px; */
}
```

The file is

> `http://greatrateprint.website/wp-content/themes/printing-shop/style.min.css?ver=1.0`

Learn to inspect your webpage it tools like [chrome inspector.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)